# How to Publish Test Results in Azure DevOps

Tags: node.js, junit, azure-devops, mocha.js

I have created the below YAML file with the PublishTestResults task to display the mocha test results in Azure DevOps portal

```yaml
# Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.14.1'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
    mocha test --reporter mocha-junit-reporter
    npm test
  displayName: 'npm install and test'

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  condition: succeededOrFailed()
  inputs:
    testRunner: JUnit
    testResultsFiles: '**/TEST-RESULTS.xml'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: 'Archive $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/node.zip'

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
```

but whenever I run the build I am getting the following warning

```
"No test result files matching **/TEST-RESULTS.xml were found."
```

The main motive is to display the mocha test results separately in a dashboard or a test tab. So that we don't have to check the test task in build process to see the test results.

Comment: And when you run those tests locally, do you think it *does* create test result files named `TEST-RESULTS.xml`?

Comment: yes it creates a file test-results.xml in my local

Comment: Hi @vigneshramesh, The PublishTestResults task default search path is $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), in the next task, we could see that you archive the Root folder $(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory), could you please check the node.zip file and ensure that it contain the file TEST-RESULTS.xml? Please check it and then kindly share the result here.

Comment: Hi @vigneshramesh, Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I encountered same issue,
After trying bunch of things could solve it as below.

**Step 1. Update package.json**

1. Include in `scripts` section:

   ```json
   "test": "cross-env CI=true react-scripts test --env=jsdom
   --testPathIgnorePatterns=assets --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit"
   ```
2. Include below in jest config *or* `jest` section in `package.json`

   ```json
   "jest-junit": {
       "suiteNameTemplate": "{filepath}",
       "outputDirectory": ".",
       "outputName": "junit.xml"
   }
   ```

   Run `npm run test` locally and see if `junit.xml` is created.

**Step 2. In Azure Pipeline YAML file**

1. Include an `Npm` task with custom command as below

   ```yaml
   - task: Npm@1
     displayName: 'Run Tests'
     inputs:
       command: 'custom'
       workingDir: "folder where your package.json exists"
       customCommand: 'test'
   ```
2. Task to publish Results

   ```yaml
   - task: PublishTestResults@2
     displayName: 'Publish Unit Test Results'
     condition: succeededOrFailed()
     inputs:
         testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
         testResultsFiles: '**/junit.xml'
         mergeTestResults: true
         failTaskOnFailedTests: true
         testRunTitle: 'React App Test'
   ```

[Publish Test Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceuZT.png)

Comment: I notice the question was regarding mocha and the accepted answer was talking about jest. Are jest settings read by mocha?

Comment: I have the same question, this is not helpful.

Answer (score 2):

What did help me to publish mocha test results was:

- First include mocha-junit-reporter in your package.json

```
npm install mocha-junit-reporter
```

- In package.json inside **scripts** section:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "mocha --reporter mocha-junit-reporter"
  }
```

- Then publish tests results:

```
 - task: PublishTestResults@2
   displayName: 'Publish Test Results **/test-results.xml'
   inputs:
     testResultsFiles: '**/test-results.xml'
   condition: succeededOrFailed()
```

Full azure devops pipeline to run mocha tests and publish results:

```
steps:
 - task: NodeTool@0
   inputs:
    versionSpec: '18.x'
   displayName: "Install Node.js"
   
 - script: |
      npm install
      npm test
   workingDirectory: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/E2E
   displayName: "npm install and Run mocha tests"
 - task: PublishTestResults@2
   displayName: 'Publish Test Results'
   inputs:
    testResultsFiles: '**/test-results.xml'
   condition: succeededOrFailed()
```